# Is it possible to view all services/types registered to StructureMap?

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I am just trying out structuremap and would like to be able to see which of my classes are registered for which service.

For example with castle windsor I can bring up the debugger and view container.Kernel.GraphNodes to see a list of all currently registered service/type pairings.

Is there a similar view into StructureMap internals?  Again, this is only something I intend to use to help familiarize myself with its registry dsl.

Answer (score 1):

ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave() or container.WhatDoIHave() where container is a Container. A link might be useful : http://nhibernate.codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2008/11/30/a-gentle-quickstart-for-structuremap-2-5.aspx